# Windows 10 でのOpen3Dのビルドに失敗する

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

Open3DをC++で使用したいため、公式の記事を参考にビルドを行っていますが通りません。

[Open3Dの公式ビルド手順](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/compilation.html)

また、環境は以下です。

Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017
cmake 3.19.5

2点返答をいただけたら幸いです。

1. ビルド済みのObjectファイル等は存在するのでしょうか
2. ビルドに成功した方、cmakeでのConfigureを実行する際に選択したオプションは何を選択しましたでしょうか

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 参照先の環境はVisualStudio2019なので、そちらに切り替えた方がよいのでは？ ただ参照先はPython用の設定的な部分が大きいのでは？ こちらはC++向けの記事らしいですが、こちらもVisualStudio2019ですし。[C++のOpen3Dをビルドしてexampleを動作させる](https://qiita.com/UnagiHuman/items/9ad9da06101e089e1df9) 一応こんなIssueもありますが、2年前の状況なので、環境を揃えるのも大変でしょう。[Questions and errors installing C++ Open3D #886](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/issues/886)

Answer (score 0):

kunifさん
アドバイスありがとうございます。
結論といたしまして、ビルド完了及びc++での動作確認まで辿り着けました。
原因は、対象ソースのバージョンの選定にズレがあった事と、サブモジュールの取得が上手くいっていなかったことでした。

Comment: 2重にアカウントを作られたようなので、このヘルプ [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) を参考にお問い合わせフォームからアカウントのマージを依頼してみてください。それから他の人のために、具体的に何のソース版数が何と合わなくて何版にしたとか、どのサブモジュールの取得が上手くいかなくてどのようにしたら出来たかといった詳細を追記してみてください。